# Import collada to meshlab with local axis

Tags: local, axis, collada, meshlab

I made a 3d model in blender, it has multiple parts, each part has its own axis with a different rotation, I exported the parts to collada, is it possible to import them into meshlab with that specific local axis' position and rotation?

Comment: This question might be better suited to https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why so? I have absolutely no problem with importing or exporting in blender, it's about meshlab and collada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe that this is possible. Meshlab has no concept of local axes, there is just the global coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, may I assume that importing a file into meshlab then exporting it reset the axis to the center of the world?